# webpack Exit status 4294967295 when trying to compile react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

I am trying to create my first react project and trying a tutorial. I am basing my webpack config off of that sample project, however when I run webpack, I get an error. Here is the npm-debug log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\daford\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'production' ]
2 info using npm@3.8.6
3 info using node@v5.10.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'preproduction', 'production', 'postproduction' ]
5 info lifecycle nestlepronourish@1.0.0~preproduction: nestlepronourish@1.0.0
6 silly lifecycle nestlepronourish@1.0.0~preproduction: no script for preproduction, continuing
7 info lifecycle nestlepronourish@1.0.0~production: nestlepronourish@1.0.0
8 verbose lifecycle nestlepronourish@1.0.0~production: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle nestlepronourish@1.0.0~production: PATH: C:\Users\daford\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\daford\Projects\nestlepronourish.v2\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Ruby21-x64\bin;C:\cygwin64\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Scripts\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files (x86)\GitExtensions\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Ruby21-x64\bin;C:\Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0;C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\bin;C:\gitflow;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5 & MySQL Utilities 1.5\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5 & MySQL Utilities 1.5\Doctrine extensions for PHP\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Bitvise SSH Client;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Scripts\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\daford\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32;C:\Users\daford\AppData\Roaming\npm
10 verbose lifecycle nestlepronourish@1.0.0~production: CWD: C:\Users\daford\Projects\nestlepronourish.v2
11 silly lifecycle nestlepronourish@1.0.0~production: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'webpack -p' ]
12 silly lifecycle nestlepronourish@1.0.0~production: Returned: code: 4294967295  signal: null
13 info lifecycle nestlepronourish@1.0.0~production: Failed to exec production script
14 verbose stack Error: nestlepronourish@1.0.0 production: `webpack -p`
14 verbose stack Exit status 4294967295
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\daford\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:239:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:185:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\daford\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:24:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:185:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:850:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:5)
15 verbose pkgid nestlepronourish@1.0.0
16 verbose cwd C:\Users\daford\Projects\nestlepronourish.v2
17 error Windows_NT 6.1.7601
18 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\daford\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "production"
19 error node v5.10.0
20 error npm  v3.8.6
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error nestlepronourish@1.0.0 production: `webpack -p`
22 error Exit status 4294967295
23 error Failed at the nestlepronourish@1.0.0 production script 'webpack -p'.
23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the nestlepronourish package,
23 error not with npm itself.
23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
23 error     webpack -p
23 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
23 error     npm bugs nestlepronourish
23 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
23 error     npm owner ls nestlepronourish
23 error There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I have tried searching but cannot figure out what the issue is. My npm version is 3.8.6 and my node version is 5.10.0

I am just starting so I only have a Hello World React compoment so far.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a syntax error in the webpack.config.js file. I put `module.export = {...}` when it should have been `module.exports={...}`

Answer (score 0):

The error with error no.4294967295 occurs when your

> current host and your Linux Subsystem connection timed out and did not
> respond.

- For more info:
  https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/terminal-exiting-with-code-4294967295-every-time/920b405b-38df-435b-bd31-550ce29f31c8
- try whitelisting your IPs if your current host is trying to connect to remote servers